# pip install with ensurepip on PyPy3.5 v5.10 in Windows 7 x64

Tags: python, windows, pip, installation, pypy

Why I can't install pip with `pypy3 -m ensurepip`? I have unpacked PyPy from [official package](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/downloads/pypy3-v5.10.0-win32.zip), and followed instructions at [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/ensurepip.html) but resulting in an error. Interpreter log is below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\pypy3-v5.10.0-win32\lib-python\3\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "D:\pypy3-v5.10.0-win32\lib-python\3\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\pypy3-v5.10.0-win32\lib-python\3\ensurepip\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
    ensurepip._main()
  File "D:\pypy3-v5.10.0-win32\lib-python\3\ensurepip\__init__.py", line 209, in _main
    default_pip=args.default_pip,
  File "D:\pypy3-v5.10.0-win32\lib-python\3\ensurepip\__init__.py", line 116, in bootstrap
    _run_pip(args + [p[0] for p in _PROJECTS], additional_paths)
  File "D:\pypy3-v5.10.0-win32\lib-python\3\ensurepip\__init__.py", line 40, in _run_pip
    import pip
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp5zq6hqua\pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl\pip\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp5zq6hqua\pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl\pip\_vendor\requests\__init__.py", line 62, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp5zq6hqua\pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp5zq6hqua\pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp5zq6hqua\pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 101, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'errno' has no attribute 'EWOULDBLOCK'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We build nightly zip files off the latest HEAD, available [here](http://buildbot.pypy.org/nightly/py3.5/). It would be great if you could try out the latest windows version and let us know on IRC at #pypy, or on the [pypy-dev](https://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/pypy-dev) mailing list, or by filing an issue on our [bitbucket issue tracker](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/issues?status=new&status=open) whether it works for you, so that we will not need to do a 5.10.2 bug release fix after the current one.

Comment: May I unpack the nightly package over my 5.10.0 installation? And at which server the IRC channel is?

Comment: Issue at Bitbucket is created.

Comment: You can either unpack over- or next-to-, you can have multiple python/pypy implementations next to eachother as long as you do not depend on your PATH environment variable to select between them, but refer to the exact exe you wish to use

Comment: Link to issue: https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/issues/2720/ensurepip-on-pypy-c-jit-93579-a4194a67868f

Answer (score 3):

The errno module on pypy3 on Windows (which is beta) is indeed incomplete.  This has been fixed after the 5.10.0 release and will be included in the 5.10.1 release.

Comment: When is 5.10.1 due for release?